# Powershell Script Issue with SQL Server 2012/2014

Tags: sql-server, powershell, named-instance

I have a PowerShell script which works well when I run it on server with SQL Server default instance (`MSSQLSERVER`) but the same script fails on a server with a named instance (`MSSQL$instance`)

For the default instance (`MSSQLSERVER`)

```
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo")
$service = Get-service -name 'MSSQLSERVER'
$status = $service.status
$CreateDB = "db-Test"

if ( $status -eq "Running" )
{ 
    'Success' | Out-File -FilePath c:\sqltest.log -Encoding ASCII

    $srv = new-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server("(local)")
    $db = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Database($srv, "$CreateDB")
    $db.Create()
    $db.CreateDate
}
else
{
    'Failed' | Out-File -FilePath c:\sqltest.log -Encoding ASCII
}
```

Above script works very well. But below script throws error :

For named instance :

```
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo")
$service = Get-service -name 'MSSQL$instancename'
$status = $service.status
$CreateDB = "db-Test"

if ( $status -eq "Running" )
{ 
     'Success' | Out-File -FilePath c:\sqltest.log -Encoding ASCII

     $srv = new-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server("(local)")
     $db = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Database($srv, "$CreateDB")
     $db.Create()
     $db.CreateDate
}
else
{
     'Failed' | Out-File -FilePath c:\sqltest.log -Encoding ASCII
}
```

Above script for named SQL instance throws below error :

> New-Object : Exception calling ".ctor" with "2" argument(s): "SetParent failed for Database 'Netmagic-Test'. "
>   At C:\mssql-test.ps1:11 char:7
>   + $db = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Database($srv, "$CreateDB")
>   +       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [New-Object], MethodInvocationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ConstructorInvokedThrowException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand
>
> You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
>   At C:\mssql-test.ps1:12 char:1
>   + $db.Create()
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

[Error Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y9yd9.jpg)

Thanks,

Viral

Comment: What happens when you change the instance name to `Get-service -name "MSSQL$instancename"`

Comment: I run the script and it throws the error mentioned at the end of my question.

Comment: Is your SQL named Instance `local`? A few different methods are discussed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8048822/is-it-possible-to-create-a-database-in-sql-server-with-powershell)

Comment: When you connect to a **named** instance, you must also use the **instance name** in your "server/instance name" - so you **cannot** use `(local)` as your server name - it has to be `(local)\INSTANCE` .....