# Arm template for creating new sql database in Azure virtual machine

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure, cloud, azure-resource-manager

I can create single database in Azure SQL Database using ARM template but what are the changes required to create a new database in virtual machine if does not exists.

ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-single-database-get-started-template

Comment: you want to create a vm with sql already installed?

Comment: VM is already available with sql server installed, I just want to create new database in existing sql server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ARM should not be used in this case, as it's used to create azure resources. Once the vm is ready, you'll need something else to create new databases. You can run powershell scripts: 
[Is it possible to create a Database in SQL Server with powershell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8048822/is-it-possible-to-create-a-database-in-sql-server-with-powershell)